# One line plot per row for multiple rows (ggplot or base R?)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
test_new <- structure(list(PS_position = c(12871487, 12997222, 12861487, 
 12871491, 12934355), Region_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
 1L), .Label = c("D", "D_left", "D_right"), class = "factor"), 
 chr_key = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), start = c(12871487, 12871487, 
 12871487, 12871487, 12871487), stop = c(12997222, 12997222, 
 12997222, 12997222, 12997222), exact_center = c(12934355, 
 12934355, 12934355, 12934355, 12934355)), .Names = c("PS_position", 
 "Region_ID", "chr_key", "start", "stop", "exact_center"), row.names = c(1L, 
 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make a plot per row, where start, stop and center remain constant for each region and one by one the PS_position gets added as a point as follows (words don't need to be there on the plot and the PS_position marker can be anything else):
[image: desired plot]

This was hard to do in ggplot as geom_vline() and geom_hline():

```
ggplot(test_new) + geom_vline(xintercept = 12871487) + geom_vline(xintercept = 12997222) + geom_vline(xintercept = 12934355)
```

So I tried base R with an example:

```
plot(1,1)
lines(c(0.8, 1.2), c(0.6, 0.6))
abline(v = 1, col = "gray60")
abline(v=1.2, col = "gray60")
abline(v=0.8, col = "gray60")
```

As is apparent, these strategies are a long way away from the desired plot. So my questions are how to best make the desired plot for a single row and how to iterate over it for further rows maintaining the points from the previous row?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to iteratively build the plot with each step separately?

Comment: Hi! Yes I want one plot per row of the dataframe, maintaining the start, stop, exact center and PS_position from previous row/previous plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Reduce(
  function(plot, position) {
    plot + annotate(
      geom = "point", 
      x = position, y = 1, 
      shape = 18, size = 5)
  }, 
  test_new$PS_position, 
  init = ggplot() + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      panel.grid =element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_blank()) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(12871487, 12934355, 12997222), color = "red"),
  accumulate = TRUE)
```

Will build a list of plots with the points added iteratively that looks pretty close to what you have in mind with the last plot looking like this

[image]

## Edit

Grouped by data frame using dplyr, tidyr and purrr. This is just grouping by Region_ID, nesting and running the same reduction for each dataframe within the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

test_new %>%
  group_by(Region_ID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plots = map(data, ~Reduce(
    function(plot, position) {
      plot + annotate(
        geom = "point", 
        x = position, y = 1, 
        shape = 18, size = 5)
    }, 
    .$PS_position, 
    init = ggplot() + 
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        panel.grid =element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank()) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(12871487, 12934355, 12997222), color = "red"),
    accumulate = TRUE)))
```

Comment: That is so cool! Thanks! Two questions, though:
i. Can there be 1 independent plot per line. So 5 plots in total for the above example.
ii. What is the xintercept changes for a different region. Can it break and a plot a new series of plots for the next region. I will update my example to reflect that.

Comment: I edited my input example above. So can it plot a different series of plots for region D and another series of plots for region D_left? thanks!

Comment: Regarding the second comment see my updated answer, not sure I understand the first question do you want it not to be cumulative?

Comment: Hi Robin, please disregard the first question, your solution works perfectly fine. I have accepted your solution. I do have one last question. How do I save this list of objects as a pdf? I tried the following after naming your code output as `list`:
`library(gridExtra)
pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(list))) {
  do.call("grid.arrange", list[[i]])  
}
dev.off()` but it throws an error: `only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"` even when each item in list is a `ggplot` object? Thanks*n

Comment: this currently returns a dataframe with a listcolumn list$plots containing lists (one for each region) of plots (one for each data point). you can access them via `list$plots[[1]][[1]]`

Comment: If you iterate over list you'll iterate over the columns. For your `do.call` to `grid.arrange` you'd supply `list$plots[[i]]` instead of `list[[i]]`.